# Unable to see viewset with update method in API page

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have few Viewsets inheriting `viewsets.ViewSet` and contain override `list()` method. I have registered all these Viewsets on API page.

Now I have one more viewset which override `update()` but I am not able to see it on API page.

This is my code:

```
class ReadNotificationsAPI(viewsets.ViewSet):
"""
   Custom API for to mark notifications as read by recipient
"""
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def update(self, request, pk=None):
    # some operations
    response_obj = {'response': 'success'}
    return Response(response_obj, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

entry in routers:

`router.register(r'readnotificationsapi', notification_views.ReadNotificationsAPI, 'readnotificationsapi')`

Other custom views that only have `list()` are visible on API page, but not this one.
Any help?

Comment: I can't understand your issue. Your issue is not clear. Please give us more information about your issue. Also if you get any error please leave us a full error trace here.

Comment: added more details.